# Composer in docker: where and how to set cache dir

Tags: docker, yii2, composer-php, docker-compose, dockerfile

I clone one project based on Yii2 in docker to create another with same architecture.

When i try up container, i have problem with prescript vendor.

```
 php_1    | + gosu www-data composer config -g github-oauth.github.com <token>
php_1    | Cannot create cache directory /home/oldproject/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
php_1    | Cannot create cache directory /home/oldproject/.composer/cache/files/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
php_1    |
php_1    |
php_1    |   [ErrorException]
php_1    |   touch(): Unable to create file /home/oldproject/.composer/config.json because No such file or directory
```

Of course this happen because i do not have path like `/home/oldproject/` but have `/home/newproject/`

I cannot find where can i adjust cache dir for composer. Also a do not understand why composer try to touch file in dir with old name.

Composer install in Dockerfile

```
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

volumes mount in compose

```
volumes:
  - ./app:/home/newproject/app
  - ./docker/runtime/.config/composer:/home/newproject/.composer
  - composer:/home/newproject/.composer
```

Comment: Composer saves his cached data (including paths to them) depending on path in which it executed (as default project root), so **after copy you must remove composer's all generated files** (e.g. you can remove composer.lock as well) and keep only composer.json (and config files created by you). It will force composer to regenerate files depending on new path.

Comment: Set the enviroment variable COMPOSER_HOME=$(pwd) to overwrite the .composer folder